# Django - .ajax() method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm writing Ajax code to hit the database to edit model instances. But the code is not working well. The first `alert` statement does work, but not the other `alert` statements. Code in `success` or `error` does not respond. Everything seems good. I have no idea how this happened though.

**book/detail.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:add_to_cart" %}',
                // handle a successful response
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Testing.");
                    ("#cartButton").text("Cart" + "(" + response.quantity + ")");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Got an error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**cart.view.py:**

```
def add_books(request):
    c = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
    q = request.GET.get('quantity')
    book_id = request.GET.get('bookID')

        <some code here>

    response = {
        'quantity': BooksInCart.objects.filter(cart=c).aggregate(item_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['item_quantity']
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

**cart.urls:**

```
app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_books/', views.add_books, name='add_to_cart')
]
```

Comment: Does the JavaScript console shows some errors? Or do you see a response in the network console? Note that since you make changes to the data, this should be a POST request, not a GET request.

Comment: what's alter statement ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `GET /book/go-action/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=LKJNw3TeeJAhswAkoLIQj3NRtpYuSq1IGc4MPoT7Fv6nlCHSD4WI51XnuKneTd4V&quantity=1&bookID=+11+ HTTP/1.1" 200 11745`. Is this what you want?

Comment: So you make a query, can you in the browser see the response?

Comment: @rakwouen sorry, that's a stupid mistake

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It was `http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/go-action/`, once I clicked the button, it changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/book/go-action/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=2xIzgMcPjny3lFQhadquwLYDpBAeV9oQXZ3yz7cIK949eLXPpwEmiJ89qWZYWWr3&quantity=1&bookID=+11+`. That's what I can see.

Comment: @Jinx: but in the network console (like in Firefox) you can see exactly what content is returned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing data in the database, you should be using a post-type request.  Include `method: 'POST'` and the csrf token in your ajax call and then check for for a post-type request in your view:
`if request.method == 'POST':`

To set the csrf token put `{% csrf_token %}` in your template in order to render the token, and then user JQuery to load the token value into the `data` portion of the `ajax` call:
`data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()}`

Comment: but each time I used POST method, then do something like `q = request.POST["quantity"]`, the page is not loading. `"POST /book/go-action/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0`